# function Dialog Box 2 buttons not working in condition

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I know this is a very simple question for all of you but I am a beginner and I am trying to figure out, how to call dialog box with 2 buttons along with parameters inside a conditional statement. My code is not invoking the function. It just displays an alert message. If someone can enlighten the error, I will really appreciate it thank you.

```
<div id="requirement #2">

  <button type="button" id="button4" onclick="StringSearch1()">Search</button>
</div>
<script>
 function StringSearch1() {
        if (condition) {

           stayonPage1(val1,val2,val3);
          //  alert("textfield1 " + val1 + " Exists in textfield2 and its corresponding value in text 3 is " + val3);
           //the alert message is working but I want to call the function dialogbox  to pop
        } else {
           //  alert("textfield1 " + val1 + " not Exists in textfield2 and its corresponding value in text 3 is " + val3)
        }
    }
      function stayonPage1(val1,val2,val3){
     var dialog = $("textfield1 " + val1 + " Exists in textfield2 and its corresponding value in text 3 is " + val3).dialog({
            buttons: {
                "Apply": function() {alert('you chose yes');},

                "Cancel":  function() {
                    dialog.dialog('close');
                }
            }
     });

        }

    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use confirm box where two button used.

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    
    <style>
       
    </style>
 </head >

<body>


    <div id="requirement #2">

        <button type="button" id="button4" onclick="StringSearch1()">Search</button>
    </div>


   
    <script>


        function StringSearch1() {
            var condition = true;
            var val1 = '1', val2 = '2', val3 = '3';
            if (condition) {

                stayonPage1(val1, val2, val3);
              


            } else {
                
            }
        }
        function stayonPage1(val1, val2, val3) {

            var Val = confirm("textfield1 " + val1 + " Exists in textfield2 and its corresponding value in text 3 is " + val3);
            if (Val == true) {
                alert('you chose yes');
                return true;
            }
            else {
                alert("close");
                return false;
            } 
            //var dialog = $("textfield1 " + val1 + " Exists in textfield2 and its corresponding value in text 3 is " + val3).dialog({
            //    buttons: {
            //        "Apply": function () { alert('you chose yes'); },

            //        "Cancel": function () {
            //            dialog.dialog('close');
            //        }
            //    }
            //});

        }

    </script>
</body>
 </html >
```

Comment: but need to custom the button text